# Pandas Dataframe increased or decreased in a certain amount of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multiple-columns

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

[image]

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd


# initialize list of lists
data = [['R.04T', 1, 2013, 23456, 22, 1 ], ['R.04T', 15, 2014, 
23456, 22, 1], ['F.04T', 9, 2010, 75920, 00, 3], ['F.04T', 4, 
2012,  75920, 00, 3], ['R.04T', 7,  2013, 20054, 13, 1], 
['R.04T',12,  2014, 20058,13, 1]]


# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['product_code', 'sold', 'year', 'city_number', 
'district_number', 'number_of_the_department'])
print(df)
```

I want to know if the locations ('city_number' + 'district_number' + 'number_of_the_department') have increased or decreased the amount of sales per year, per article. Id thought about joining the columns to one location column like the following:

```
# join the locations
df['location'] = df['city_number'].astype(str) + ','+ 
df['district_number'].astype(str) + ','+ df['number_of_the_department'].astype(str)
```

But I'm not sure how to groupby? the df to get my answer of the question.

I want to know if the sales have increased or decreased (per year and item) by a certain percentage per year (p.ex. 2013 to 2014 x% decreased).

Maybe someone can help? :)

Comment: I'm not so sure how you want the output to be... but if you do `df2 = df.groupby['product_code','year,'location']).max()` it'll be easy to visualize all articles together and see which year had best sales.

Comment: Thank you. I want to get a new dataframe where I can see the years where one product in one location increases in the "sold" category for about (lets say 40%). Maybe I can try to visualize that better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.assign(
    pct_change_sold=df.sort_values(by="year")
    .groupby(by=["city_number", "district_number", "number_of_the_department"])["sold"]
    .pct_change()
    .fillna(0)
)
```

---

```
  product_code  sold  year  city_number  district_number  number_of_the_department  pct_change_sold
0        R.04T     1  2013        23456               22                         1         0.000000
1        R.04T    15  2014        23456               22                         1        14.000000
2        F.04T     9  2010        75920                0                         3         0.000000
3        F.04T     4  2012        75920                0                         3        -0.555556
4        R.04T     7  2006        75920               22                         1         0.000000
5        U.90G    12  2005        75021               34                         3         0.000000
```

Comment: It looks quite perfect!! But there is one thing I don't get: with the product F.04T there is no %change,  even if the "sold" section changes. And when I look at the index 4: R.04T - where is the -0.55 coming from? From 7 to 1 its 85,71% less and from 7 to 15 its  114,28% more. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Looking into it

Comment: fixed, edited post.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but it isnt working right now...

Comment: Can you tell me what's not working? The output I'm seeing looks expected with regards to the pct_change calculation., i.e 140% improvement (14.0) for the first group, next group has a decline 55% and last two groups only have one observation, pct change will return null.

Comment: I think i got it. I'd made a mistake while giving you the df. Bc the location is always the same as the product code. So the product code isn't included in the skript although it should be, bc one Item can be sold by any location. Let me quickly fix that.

Comment: Got it. Just added "product code" and it worked. Thank you!